# Config ModelMapper giving me an error when converting From a Set<Author> to Set<Integer>

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, modelmapper

I am trying to convert a book class (livro) to a bookDto. I was tryied doing that creating a bean config of model mapper but it is not working.
I have on the book class a Set of Authors (autores) and a Set of Genre (generos) and all classes have Integers ids. I want the BookDTO to have only a set of the ids. I guess the problem is on the model mapper config i did

```
package br.com.newgo.biblioteca.config;

import br.com.newgo.biblioteca.data.dto.output.LivroCriadoDto;
import br.com.newgo.biblioteca.data.entity.Autor;
import br.com.newgo.biblioteca.data.entity.Genero;
import br.com.newgo.biblioteca.data.entity.Livro;
import org.modelmapper.Converter;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Configuration
public class MapperConfig {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper(){
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

        Converter<Set<Autor>, Set<Integer>> autoresParaAutoresId = context -> {
            if (context.getSource() == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return context.getSource().stream()
                    .map(Autor::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        };

        Converter<Set<Genero>, Set<Integer>> generosParaGenerosId = context -> {
            if (context.getSource() == null){
                return null;
            }
            return context.getSource().stream()
                    .map(Genero::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        };
        modelMapper.typeMap(Livro.class , LivroCriadoDto.class).addMappings(
                src -> {
                    src.using(autoresParaAutoresId).map(Livro::getAutores, LivroCriadoDto::setAutores);
                    src.using(generosParaGenerosId).map(Livro::getGeneros, LivroCriadoDto::setGeneros);
                });

        return modelMapper;
    }

}
```

Here is my book class:

```
package br.com.newgo.biblioteca.data.entity;


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity()
@Table(name = "livros")
public class Livro {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nome;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 13)
    private String isbn;
    //de 10 ou 13?
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Float valor;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer paginas;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Float altura;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Float largura;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Float profundidade;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "livro_genero")
    private Set<Genero> generos = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "livro_autor",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "livro_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "autor_id"))
    private Set<Autor> autores = new HashSet<>();


}
```

and here is the dto i am trying to convert to :

```
package br.com.newgo.biblioteca.data.dto.output;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Positive;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LivroCriadoDto {

    @NotNull
    private Integer id;
    @NotBlank
    private String nome;
    @NotBlank
    @Length(min = 10, max = 13)
    private String isbn;
    @NotNull
    @Positive
    private Float valor;
    @NotNull
    @Positive
    private Integer paginas;
    @NotNull
    @Positive
    private Float altura;
    @NotNull
    @Positive
    private Float largura;
    @NotNull
    @Positive
    private Float profundidade;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private Set<Integer> generos = new HashSet<>();
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private Set<Integer> autores = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I am trying doing this

```
modelMapper.map(livro, LivroCriadoDto.class);
```

and it is returning me

```
Converter br.com.newgo.biblioteca.config.MapperConfig$$Lambda$1243/0x000000080140e3d8@16a95f37 failed to convert org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentSet to java.util.Set.


1) Converter br.com.newgo.biblioteca.config.MapperConfig$$Lambda$1243/0x000000080140e3d8@16a95f37 failed to convert org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentSet to java.util.Set.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at br.com.newgo.biblioteca.config.MapperConfig.lambda$modelMapper$0(MapperConfig.java:27)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.convert(MappingEngineImpl.java:306)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.setDestinationValue(MappingEngineImpl.java:243)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.propertyMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:187)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:151)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:105)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:71)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.mapInternal(ModelMapper.java:589)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:422)
    at br.com.newgo.biblioteca.domain.services.LivroService.cadastrar(LivroService.java:51)
    at br.com.newgo.biblioteca.presentation.controllers.LivroController.cadastrar(LivroController.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:913)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that jpa was creating a Autor and Genero null because it was not supposed to be null and passing it no Livro